# Hide every directory in a folder from index, but not their contents

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, httpd, indexing

On my server, I want to create a directory hidden from normal users, but that is accessible with a link without authentication.

Currently I have set it up like this:

- In the virtual host configuration I have allowed Index options to be overridden
- On my server I have folder called `h`, as in hidden
- On the same level with `h` I have a `.htaccess` file with: `IndexIgnore h`
- And in h another `.htaccess` with `IndexIgnore *`

However, that also hides the contents of `h/abc/`, which I don't want. I tried putting `IndexIgnore .` in `h/abc/.htaccess`, but it did not work. It is also stated in [HTTPD Docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_autoindex.html#indexignore), which I learned later on:

> Multiple IndexIgnore directives add to the list, rather than the
>   replacing the list of ignored files. By default, the list contains .
>   (the current directory).

Is there a way to specify the `IndexIgnore` to only act on items inside the current directory, and not be recursive?

Or is there some kind of other, better way to deal with this? I would prefer not to touch the "global" configuration files too much, altough that is possible.

Answer (score 2):

Placing the directory outside of your document root and creating an `Alias` would get you what you want.  That is, assuming your document root is something like `/var/www/html`, you would create `/var/www/private` and then add (to your global -- sorry -- configuration):

```
Alias /private/ /var/www/private/
```

This directory would not show up in a list of files in `/` (because it's not contained in that directory), but it would work just fine if requested explicitly.

Comment: Is it possible to do it so that you can not see the contents of /private/, but you can see /private/abc/? So I could just create multiple "private folders" for different people, or would I have to alias them separately?

Comment: You could get the behavior you want with more `Alias` directives, certainly.  I'm still a little fuzzy on your actual use case, so I may be providing the best answer.